# Is it possible to Filter and Sort at the same time with in a single template using Class Based Generic ListView? If yes, how?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-filter

I have a template which shows the list of all the products in a template using ListView. I have this link for the sorting using different parameters on my model Product.

Below is a snippet from my Template.

```
<th>
     <span> Product &nbsp; </span>
        <a class="fa fa-sort-up fa-lg" href="{% url 'admin:product_list' %}?sort_by=name"></a>
</th>

{% for product in products %}

<td><a href="{% url 'admin:product_update' pk=product.pk %}">{{ product.name }}</a></td>
```

and the url that refers to a ListView called "ProductListView" is -

```
path('products/list/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

and ProductListView is as folllows -

```
class ProductListView(UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'admin_app/product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('sort_by')
        return ordering

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

I have a search box like this

```
<form method="get" class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Products...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I just want to know the path of how can I use the Search box to show me queries. I can redirect all the queries to a different page but is it possible to implement the queries on the same page? and then apply sorting on these queries.

For example if I search ***example_product***, then I want to show all the products/categories that contain this string and then I want to sort the results based on the latest/name/availability etc.

Comment: I'd suggest investigating Django-filter https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductListView(UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'admin_app/product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        query_string = self.request.GET['q'].strip()
        search_fields = [
            'the', 'fields', 'you','want', 'to', 'search'
            ]
        entry_query = get_query(query_string, search_fields)
        items_per_search = 20

        found_entries = qs.filter(entry_query)\
                .distinct().order_by('whateverTheOrderFieldIs'[:items_per_search]

        return found_entries
```